# Hotswap Lipo Circuit for Tegra TX2 Dk

Tags: power-supply, lipo, discharge

I am currently working on my hexapod project that involves an Nvidia Tegra TX2 Development kit. The issue is as follows:
The Tegra (as the hexapod should be able to operate autonomously) is powered from a 6s Lipo battery which is able to supply enough electricity for a decent amount of time. However I would like to be able to hotswap the lipo battery (for the same model) and would like to know if and how this is possible. I am NOT intending to buy the 100 USD PowerBoard from Sainsmart.

Today I had a discussion with my instructor who recommended the following circuit:

[image]

Using the 2 Zehner Diodes the Lipos should be able to power the circuit without interruption and not destroying each other by loading.

I am sorry my electrical engineering skills are not very advanced even though I have a bachelor in applied physiks. So if anybody could help that would be great. If you need further clarification please let me know!

Comment: If the voltage drop (~0.4V) of a Schottky diode is not acceptable you can search for MOSFET-based "ideal diodes", like e.g. http://www.linear.com/product/LTC4358

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That circuit is roughly correct, however you don't want to use Zener diodes. Zener diodes are intended to be driven reverse biased, which this application doesn't need/want. Instead, look for a Schottky diode. These diodes have a relatively low forward voltage meaning lower power loss in the diode.